# In Android, is there a proguard rule that keeps all inner objects of a class and protects them against obfuscation?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I have some dagger classes in an android SDK that need to be protected from minification and obfuscation when creating and publishing the release version. I protect those by using custom proguard rules around the @Module and @DaggerGenerated annotations.

```
-keep @dagger.Module public class * { public <methods>; }
-keep @dagger.internal.DaggerGenerated public class * {public <methods>;}
```

Some of those classes have companion objects that should also be protected. At the moment, I protect them by annotating the companions specifically with @Keep. Is there a way to specify a proguard rule to automatically keep the companion?

I tried a few variations such as the one below but none of them got the job done.

```
-keep @dagger.Module class *$Companion { *; }
```

Comment: i know this isn't ideal, but would it be possible to instead try to protect/keep an entire package, instead of trying to keep every individual file ?

Comment: good call. if I don't figure out a different I'll probably go for this. thanks

Comment: i'll write it as an answer in case you can't find anything else, i do think this is an interesting question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an ideal solution, but you could instead try to keep an entire package instead of individual files, using something like:

```
-keep class com.foo.bar.** { *; }
```

this way, you'll be covering any companion objects found here as well

Comment: this could work. the problem is I have a bunch of different modules that I need to publish and I wanted to create a single proguard file for all of them, which is why I opted for keeping all classes annotated with @Module. If nothing else works, I think I will your solution with a slight tweak -> -keep class **.di.** { *; }. This should keep everything as long as I conform to the di package name in all modules